# How to set state to zero at the end of every day automatically?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building water reminder app and I store daily amount of consumed water in App state and AsyncStorage.

I want to set it to zero at the end of every day automatically.

As you can see below. I am storing amount of consumed water in drunk state and calculate progress by dividing goal to drunk.

I am getting goal from AsyncStorage and set it to state.

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    progress: 0, 
    drunk: 0, // this is the state I want to set to zero
    goal: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      "willFocus",
      payload => {
        console.debug("willFocus", payload);
        //retrieve items from AsyncStorage
        _retrieveData = async key => {
          try {
            const sliderValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("sliderValue");
            const drunk = await AsyncStorage.getItem("drunk");
            const progress = await AsyncStorage.getItem("progress");
            if (drunk !== null) {
              // We have data!! and set them to states
              this.setState({
                goal: parseInt(sliderValue),
                drunk: parseInt(drunk),
                progress: parseFloat(progress)
              });
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        };
        _retrieveData();
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.willFocusSubscription) {
      this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
    }
  }

  //function to drink water, set state and setItem Async
  drinkWater = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      drunk: prevState.drunk + 200,
      progress: (prevState.drunk + 200) / this.state.goal
    }));

    let progress = this.state.progress;
    let drunk = this.state.drunk;

    _storeData = async () => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("progress", progress.toString());
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("drunk", drunk.toString());
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };

    _storeData();
  };
```

Comment: Can't give a real answer without more detail, but one general strategy might be: store a last-modified timestamp along with the data, and on load check if the timestamp is from a previous day, reset your data if so.

Comment: Thank you daniel. I have added more details and screenshot to my question. But your solution would do the work for me. Thanks

Comment: @sinan The screen shot doesn't really help. It just shows us a pretty picture. I think you should edit your question and give some information about how you are storing your data (what are you using, AsyncStorage, Realm Database, Redux), that way people would be able to suggest solutions.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @Andrew. I have added my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to do something that follows this pattern.

#### App launches

Check the date stored and compare it with the current date.  If no date is stored, store the date. Otherwise if the current date is greater than the stored date, reset the values.

#### Background to foreground

When the app comes from the background to the foreground, or even returns to the HomeScreen, check the date stored and compare it with the current date. If the current date is greater than the stored date, reset the values.

### Time

When dealing with time, `moment` is a great package to use. It is well tested. You can find out more about it here https://momentjs.com. You can install it with `npm i moment`

### Code Example

1. We are using AppState to track the whether the app is in the background or in the foreground. As the app could be running when the date changes we need to check when it comes into the foreground.
2. We need to check when the component mounts, as it will mount when the app launches. So the app could have previously been closed.
3. Ignore the times when saving dates as we only really want to compare the dates.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, AppState } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState,  // set the currentState as the appState
    }
  }
  
  async componentDidMount () {
    // Set the listener
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    // perform check when the component mounts
    await this.checkDate();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount () {
    // remove the listener
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }
  
  _handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      // app has come to the foreground
      // perform checks etc here
      await this.checkDate();
    }
    // update the appState
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
  }

  checkDate = async () => {
    // create a string with the current date
    let currentDateString = moment('YYYY-MM-DD') 
    
    // get the value from storage
    let savedDateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('storedDate');
    if (savedDateString) {

      if (moment(currentDateString).isAfter(savedDateString)) {
        // this is where you put the code that resets everything
        // clear the values that you have previously saved
        // remember to save the new date
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('storedDate', currentDateString)
        } catch (err) {
        }
      } else {
        // don't do anything as the time hasn't changed
        // so we could really get rid of this else statement
      }
    } else {
      // save the time as this is the first time the app has launched
      // do any other initial setup here
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('storedDate', currentDateString)
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The code should give you an idea on how you can implement it.